# Balancing hardware to charge my DIY 13s6p 18650 LiOn from 54.6v Smart Charger?

Tags: battery-charging

I know the cells must be balanced though I wanted to confirm that the the 54.6v "smart" charger (which made no mention of battery prerequisites) didn't some how trickle the charge into the pack in some safe way I did not know about. I would have been VERY surprised if it could.

This is my first LiOn project and I have been researching diligently. Unfortunately confirming an author's credentials is not self evident. I have discovered http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com and http://batteryuniversity.com which seem to be solid resources, but I know there are insights to be had from members here.

**Concisely, I am enquiring here for advice.**

I was advised to buy something labeled as "Charger for 13S 46.8V/48V (13S 3.6V*13/3.7V*13) Li-ion/Li-Polymer or 15S 48V (15*3.2V) rechargeable battery". There was no mention of balancing, I assume I need my battery to balance itself under these conditions. (and would be surprised otherwise. Hardware recommendations or references anyone?)

I am leaning toward constructing the "Arduino 18650 Battery Charger Project" described here: http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/arduino-18650-battery-charger-project-1/

Have spent a relative fortune for 78 Samsung 25R batteries I want to charge them right.

Comment: That arduino you link might be ok for a single cell, I didn't look closely, but certainly not for your battery pack with many in series. You need a charge controller. Don't try to build it until you understand what you're doing, 78 * 18650 cells is a **lot** of energy.

Comment: If you still have to wonder whether to balance or not, then there is a lot you are missing. Go back to square one and learn about lion batteries

Answer (score 1):

Did you read my answer to [your question that you posted 3 days ago](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/371245/need-info-about-dc-dc-boost-converter/371290#371290)?

What you need is a battery manager, or BMS. This is the current standard way to handle your problem. There may be other jankeyer solutions, such as charging your pack 6s at a time using an RC balance charger, but I wouldn't recommend them if you don't know exactly what you're doing.

Here's some examples of battery managers that I found with a quick google search.

https://vruzend.com/product/48v-13s-battery-management-system-bms/

https://bmsbattery.com/bmspcm/713-10s-13s-30a-50a-lipo-battery-bms-system-bms-pcm.html

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/48V-30A-13S-BMS-used-for-lithium-ion-battery-assembly/1250293246.html

http://www.batterysupports.com/48v-546v-13s-30a-13x-36v-lithium-ion-lipolymer-battery-bms-pcb-p-271.html

Picture in case the links die:
[image]

A battery manager is powered from the pack and will actively balance the cells. All you have to worry about is charging the pack to the correct voltage.

Comment: That is what I thought. That is must be embedded with the battery. I haver a CS degree and moderate electrical knowledge, but this is my first battery project. I did not read the answer you posted to my DC Boost question. I am about too. Respectfully, Thank you for your time. There are a lot of people who don't know shit obscurring peole like yourself.